# Is this a possible way to optimize multidimensional arrays on heap?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is a usual way to allocate multidimensional arrays on heap, by using pointers to pointers.

```
typedef struct ArrayInt {
    int *array;
    int length;
} ArrayInt;

static void ArrayIntCreate(ArrayInt *array, int length) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * sizeof(int));
    array->length = length;
}

static void ArrayIntDelete(ArrayInt *array) {
    free(array->array);
}

typedef struct ArrayArrayInt {
    ArrayInt *array;
    int length;
} ArrayArrayInt;

static void ArrayArrayIntCreate(ArrayArrayInt *array, int length, int length2) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * sizeof(ArrayInt));
    array->length = length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        ArrayIntCreate(&array->array[i], length2);
    }
}

static void ArrayArrayIntDelete(ArrayArrayInt *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array->length; i += 1) {
        ArrayIntDelete(&array->array[i]);
    }
    free(array->array);
}
```

But I decided to make a version that allocates only one chunck of memory and does element accessing by multiplication to an index value.

```
typedef struct ArrayArrayInt2 {
    int *array;
    int length;
    int length2;
} ArrayArrayInt2;

static void ArrayArrayInt2Create(ArrayArrayInt2 *array, int length, int length2) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * length2 * sizeof(ArrayInt));
    array->length = length;
    array->length2 = length2;
}

static void ArrayArrayInt2Delete(ArrayArrayInt2 *array) {
    free(array->array);
}

#define aai2At(aai2, i) (&aai2.array[i * aai2.length2])
```

<s>The second version appreas to run about 20% faster when running the test code below. What is likely to be the cause, and is this a generally applicable optimization technique? Are there some libraries that define array types of this kind for optimization purpose?</s>

*I made a huge mistake in the test code before edit. The first version ran slower because its allocation and deallocation kept place inside the for-loop while the second one did it only once before entering the loop. See the comments in the test code below. After making the two tests equal, I find that the first version can run even faster, especially after optimization. The more complex operations and various copies I put into the test code, I see the first one always run a little bit faster. It seems that the multiplication for indexing is slow in my machine? I'm not sure for the cause, though.*

```
static double ElapsedTime(clock_t startTime, clock_t endTime) {
    return (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

#define N 2000

int main() {
    ArrayArrayInt aai;
    ArrayArrayInt2 aai2;
    long long int sum;
    clock_t startTime, endTime;

    startTime = clock();             
    sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k += 1) {
        ArrayArrayIntCreate(&aai, N, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < aai.length; i += 1) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < aai.array[i].length; j += 1) {
                aai.array[i].array[j] = i;
            }
            while ((j -= 1) >= 0) {
                sum += aai.array[i].array[j] - i + 1;
            }
        }
        ArrayArrayIntDelete(&aai);
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("aai: sum = %lld; time = %.2f\n", sum, ElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    ArrayArrayInt2Create(&aai2, N, N); //Mistake Here!!
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k += 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aai2.length; i += 1) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < aai2.length2; j += 1) {
                aai2At(aai2, i)[j] = i;
            }
            while ((j -= 1) >= 0) {
                sum += aai2At(aai2, i)[j] - i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    ArrayArrayInt2Delete(&aai2); //Should go inside the loop block..
    endTime = clock();
    printf("aai2: sum = %lld; time = %.2f\n", sum, ElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an often used technique to optimize performance of allocating memory for 2D arrays. You get a performance boost by reducing the number of calls to `malloc`.

Comment: You don't need any library to use real 2D arrays and not the 2D pseudo arrays that you started with. Modern C since 1999 knows to handle this directly. Just do `int (*arr)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[m][n]));` This is called "VLA", variable length array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using arithmetic and a single base pointer is what the compiler does internally for non-dynamically allocated 2D (n-dimensional) arrays.

You gain the most performance because there's a single calculation and indexed lookup.  With the 2D array shown, there are two pointer lookups and two index calculations per array access (one index calculation and lookup to get to the right array, and then the second to access the element in the right array).  With a 3D array, there'd be three index calculations and three lookups.

You also allocate less memory, and need fewer memory allocations, but those are second order effects.

Also, as [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484112/is-this-a-possible-way-to-optimize-multidimensional-arrays-on-heap/29484266?noredirect=1#comment47128846_29484266) but I didn't mention, you get better locality of reference and potential for smarter prefetch with a single big chunk of memory compared with multiple smaller chunks (that add up to more memory than the single big chunk).

---

I tested this file (`sim2d.c`) compiled with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void *MjMalloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *rv = malloc(nbytes);
    if (rv == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure (%zu bytes)\n", nbytes);
        exit(1);
    }
    return rv;
}

/* Mechanism 1 */
typedef struct ArrayInt {
    int *array;
    int length;
} ArrayInt;

static void ArrayIntCreate(ArrayInt *array, int length) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * sizeof(int));
    array->length = length;
}

static void ArrayIntDelete(ArrayInt *array) {
    free(array->array);
}

typedef struct ArrayArrayInt {
    ArrayInt *array;
    int length;
} ArrayArrayInt;

static void ArrayArrayIntCreate(ArrayArrayInt *array, int length, int length2) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * sizeof(ArrayInt));
    array->length = length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        ArrayIntCreate(&array->array[i], length2);
    }
}

static void ArrayArrayIntDelete(ArrayArrayInt *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array->length; i += 1) {
        ArrayIntDelete(&array->array[i]);
    }
    free(array->array);
}

/* Mechanism 2 */
typedef struct ArrayArrayInt2 {
    int *array;
    int length;
    int length2;
} ArrayArrayInt2;

static void ArrayArrayInt2Create(ArrayArrayInt2 *array, int length, int length2) {
    array->array = MjMalloc(length * length2 * sizeof(ArrayInt));
    array->length = length;
    array->length2 = length2;
}

static void ArrayArrayInt2Delete(ArrayArrayInt2 *array) {
    free(array->array);
}

#define aai2At(aai2, i) (&aai2.array[(i) * aai2.length2])
#define aai2At2(aai2, i, j) (aai2.array[(i) * aai2.length2 + (j)])

/* Head-to-head testing */
static double ElapsedTime(clock_t startTime, clock_t endTime) {
    return (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

#define N 2000
#define N_CYCLES    1000

static void one_test_cycle(void)
{
    ArrayArrayInt aai;
    ArrayArrayInt2 aai2;
    long long int sum;
    clock_t startTime, endTime;

    startTime = clock();             
    sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N_CYCLES; k += 1) {
        ArrayArrayIntCreate(&aai, N, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < aai.length; i += 1) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < aai.array[i].length; j += 1) {
                aai.array[i].array[j] = i;
            }
            while ((j -= 1) >= 0) {
                sum += aai.array[i].array[j] - i + 1;
            }
        }
        ArrayArrayIntDelete(&aai);
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("aai1: sum = %lld; time = %.2f\n", sum, ElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N_CYCLES; k += 1) {
        ArrayArrayInt2Create(&aai2, N, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < aai2.length; i += 1) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < aai2.length2; j += 1) {
                aai2At(aai2, i)[j] = i;
            }
            while ((j -= 1) >= 0) {
                sum += aai2At(aai2, i)[j] - i + 1;
            }
        }
        ArrayArrayInt2Delete(&aai2);
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("aai2: sum = %lld; time = %.2f\n", sum, ElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < N_CYCLES; k += 1) {
        ArrayArrayInt2Create(&aai2, N, N);
        for (int i = 0; i < aai2.length; i += 1) {
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < aai2.length2; j += 1) {
                aai2At2(aai2, i, j) = i;
            }
            while ((j -= 1) >= 0) {
                sum += aai2At2(aai2, i, j) - i + 1;
            }
        }
        ArrayArrayInt2Delete(&aai2);
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("aai3: sum = %lld; time = %.2f\n", sum, ElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));
}

static void print_now(const char *tag)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *lt = localtime(&now);
    char buffer[32];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", lt);
    printf("%s: %s\n", tag, buffer);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_now("Started");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        one_test_cycle();
    print_now("Finished");
    return 0;
}
```

There are two slightly different ways of accessing the `aai2` data.  I also separated the array size (N = 2000) from the number of cycles in a single test (N_CYCLES = 1000).  The timing results I got were:

```
Started: 2015-04-07 07:40:41
aai1: sum = 4000000000; time = 6.80
aai2: sum = 4000000000; time = 5.99
aai3: sum = 4000000000; time = 5.98
aai1: sum = 4000000000; time = 6.75
aai2: sum = 4000000000; time = 6.02
aai3: sum = 4000000000; time = 5.99
aai1: sum = 4000000000; time = 6.72
aai2: sum = 4000000000; time = 6.01
aai3: sum = 4000000000; time = 5.99
Finished: 2015-04-07 07:41:38
```

I was getting similar patterns with (N_CYCLE = 2000), but it was taking twice as long to run — surprise, surprise.

I'm seeing a small but noticeable benefit (about 13% decrease) from the single allocation code, but no significant difference between the two timings for the 'aai2' tests.

Basic statistics:

```
# All data
# Count    = 9
# Mean     =  6.250000e+00
# Std Dev  =  3.807230e-01

# aai1 only:
# Count    = 3
# Mean     =  6.756667e+00
# Std Dev  =  4.041452e-02

# aai2 and aai3:
# Count    = 6
# Mean     =  5.996667e+00
# Std Dev  =  1.505545e-02

# aai2 only:
# Count    = 3
# Mean     =  6.006667e+00
# Std Dev  =  1.527525e-02

# aai3 only:
# Count    = 3
# Mean     =  5.986667e+00
# Std Dev  =  5.773503e-03
```

Clearly, formally making sure the machine is otherwise unloaded, and running many more iterations of the test, and similar benchmarking steps might improve the data, but the single allocation `aai2` mechanism performs better on this machine than the multi-allocation `aai` mechanism. (Tangential aside: why do people not put a suffix 1 on their first version when they have two or more versions of the code?)

<sup>*Hardware: 17" Mac Book Pro, early-2011, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GiB 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM.*</sup>

Comment: Upticked, Also with a single contiguous allocation you'll *very* likely get smarter pre-fetcher performance during ordered row/slab-enumeration. Every dime helps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I made a huge mistake in the test code of the originial post. Now I am actually getting opposite results after fix. Please see my edits.

Comment: @xiver77: see the additional material.  I'm finding a 13% improvement using the `aai2` mechanism rather than the `aai` mechanism on my machine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting result. With many tests in my machine (some random Core i5, Win7, MinGW/GCC), `aai` starts to run nearly same or even faster than `aai2` with optimization flag `-O2` or above. Without optimization, `aai2` is always faster. Not sure, but with higher optimization levels, gcc seems to optimize array of pointers in a clever way.